# listings bug: space after literate replacement lost with spaceflexible/fullflexible columns

Tags: spacing, listings, columns

Problem with space being lost in `listings` immediately after a `literate` replacement when using `columns=spaceflexible` or `columns=fullflexible` (appears correctly with `columns=flexible`).  A small example follows, with problem being that the space after the replaced operator is lost.

Note: This problem is extremely similar to [one posted earlier today](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41934), but this time, the problem involves the space after a `literate` replacement, and the space is lost in both `\lstinline` and `lstlisting` modes (previous question involved string replacement, and error occurring only in `\lstinline` mode).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{literate=*{{+}{*}{1}}, columns=fullflexible}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ll}
flexible & \lstinline[columns=flexible]!1 + 1!\\
spaceflexible & \lstinline[columns=spaceflexible]!1 + 1!\\
fullflexible & \lstinline!1 + 1!\\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\noindent
Within lstlisting environment with columns=flexible
\begin{lstlisting}[columns=flexible]
1 + 1
\end{lstlisting}

\noindent
Within lstlisting environment with columns=spaceflexible
\begin{lstlisting}[columns=spaceflexible]
1 + 1
\end{lstlisting}

\noindent
Within lstlisting environment with columns=fullflexible
\begin{lstlisting}
1 + 1
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 20):

You can use the option `keepspaces`. For more details have a look at the documentation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{literate=*{+}{*}{1}, columns=fullflexible,keepspaces}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ll}
flexible & \lstinline[columns=flexible]!1 + 1!\\
spaceflexible & \lstinline[columns=spaceflexible]!1 + 1!\\
fullflexible & \lstinline!1 + 1!\\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\noindent
Within lstlisting environment with columns=flexible
\begin{lstlisting}[columns=flexible]
1 + 1
\end{lstlisting}

\noindent
Within lstlisting environment with columns=spaceflexible
\begin{lstlisting}[columns=spaceflexible]
1 + 1
\end{lstlisting}

\noindent
Within lstlisting environment with columns=fullflexible
\begin{lstlisting}
1 + 1
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```