# How to apply the star (*) to only a few of the literates in listings environment?

Tags: listings, unicode

I have a problem with the definition of literate:

```
\lstset{
  numbers=left, numberstyle=\footnotesize, stepnumber=1, numbersep=12pt,
  frame=none, framesep=7pt,
  breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,
  showstringspaces=false,
  upquote=true,
  columns=fullflexible,
  showstringspaces=false,
  commentstyle=\color{gray}\upshape,
  stringstyle=\color{black}\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{darkblue},
  captionpos=b,
  extendedchars=true,
  literate=
  *{0}{{{\color{DarkGreen}0}}}1
  {1}{{{\color{DarkGreen}1}}}1
  {2}{{{\color{DarkGreen}2}}}1
  {3}{{{\color{DarkGreen}3}}}1
  {4}{{{\color{DarkGreen}4}}}1
  {5}{{{\color{DarkGreen}5}}}1
  {6}{{{\color{DarkGreen}6}}}1
  {7}{{{\color{DarkGreen}7}}}1
  {8}{{{\color{DarkGreen}8}}}1
  {9}{{{\color{DarkGreen}9}}}1
  {á}{{\'a}}1
  {é}{{\'e}}1
  {í}{{\'i}}1
  {ó}{{\'o}}1
  {ú}{{\'u}}1
}
```

The coloring of the numerals has the be ignored inside comments and strings (hence the * at the beginning) BUT the rules for the acute accents shouldn't. This is because source code with strings in different languages is included later with the `\lstinputlisting` option, and if the unicode characters are not changed, it crashes.

So, does anyone know any way to apply the * to only part of the literate definitions? I tried to define them in the specific listing where the file is included, but a second literate eliminates the previous definitions.

PS: I tried to change the encoding of the file with the `\inputencoding=utf8/latin1` as well, but it makes the compilation REALLY slow and returns a `Missing $ inserted.` error.

**EDIT:** I'm adding a fully compilable MWE that I think represents the problem. The output highlights the colors according to the rules defined for Javascript. However, as I said before, in line 22 (see output) the numerals are in green, even being a comment. If the * is added before the numerals, the compilation crashes because the unicode characters inside the strings are not replaced.

(NOTE: the javascript doesn't make any sense)

```
\documentclass[spanish, 11pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{underscore}


\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
  keywords={typeof, new, true, false, catch, function, return, null, catch, switch, var, if, in, while, do, else, case, break, ajax, each, get, post},
  keywordstyle=\color{darkblue}\bfseries,
  keywords=[2]{class, export, boolean, throw, implements, import, this},
  keywordstyle=[2]\color{darkgray}\bfseries,
  identifierstyle=\color{black},
  sensitive=false,
  comment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  commentstyle=\color{FireBrick}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\color{DarkOrange}\ttfamily,
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"
}

\lstdefinestyle{Javascript}{
   language=JavaScript,
   extendedchars=true,
   basicstyle=\footnotesize,
   showstringspaces=false,
   showspaces=false,
   tabsize=2,
   breaklines=true,
   showtabs=false,
   captionpos=b,
}

\lstset{
language=Javascript,
style=Javascript,
  numbers=left, numberstyle=\footnotesize, stepnumber=1, numbersep=12pt,
  frame=none, framesep=7pt,
  breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,
  showstringspaces=false,
  upquote=true,
  columns=fullflexible,
  showstringspaces=false,
  keywordstyle=\color{DarkBlue},
  captionpos=b,
  extendedchars=true,
  literate=
  {0}{{{\color{DarkGreen}0}}}1
  {1}{{{\color{DarkGreen}1}}}1
  {2}{{{\color{DarkGreen}2}}}1
  {3}{{{\color{DarkGreen}3}}}1
  {4}{{{\color{DarkGreen}4}}}1
  {5}{{{\color{DarkGreen}5}}}1
  {6}{{{\color{DarkGreen}6}}}1
  {7}{{{\color{DarkGreen}7}}}1
  {8}{{{\color{DarkGreen}8}}}1
  {9}{{{\color{DarkGreen}9}}}1
  {á}{{\'a}}1 
  {é}{{\'e}}1
  {í}{{\'i}}1
  {ó}{{\'o}}1
  {ú}{{\'u}}1
  {Á}{{\'A}}1
  {É}{{\'E}}1
  {Í}{{\'I}}1
  {Ó}{{\'O}}1
  {Ú}{{\'U}}1
  {¡}{{!`}}1
  {¿}{{?`}}1
  {·}{{$\cdot$}}1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
function manageLanguage(text)
{ // Language options in interface and errors
    switch (language)
    {
case "Welcome":
        return '¡Bienvenido a '

        case "Browse":
        return '<b>Navega</b> por tu disco duro y selecciona lo(s) fichero(s) a visualizar o simplemente <b>arrástralos</b> al área del botón'

        case "Default":
        return 'Ejemplo por Defecto'
    }

    case "Catalan":
        switch (text)
        {

        case "AlreadySession":
        return 'Ja tens una sessió oberta. Sel·lecciona Nou al menú Fitxer per tancarla i apujar nous fitxers.'

        //var start = (Math.round(this.x*100)/100);
                if (start % intervals == 0)         
                return "<b>" + manageLanguage("Interval") +":</b> [" + Math.round(this.x*10)/10 + " - " + Math.round((this.x+intervals)*10)/10+"]<br/><b>" + manageLanguage(this.series.name) + ":</b> " + this.y + " ";
                else return false; //"<b>" + manageLanguage("Interval") +":</b> [" + this.key + " - " + (this.key+intervals)+"]<br/><b>" + manageLanguage(this.series.name) + ":</b> " + this.y;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've just added an example. Sorry for not doing it at the beginning :\

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @Jubobs: Hopeless wish, I guess. Go into the user profile and see when it was last time seen.

Comment: @Speravir I know... but leaving a reminder in the comments can't hurt.

Comment: @Jubobs: Yes, you’re right.

Answer (score 10):

The following example now uses the trick of [Jubobs' comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83544/how-to-apply-the-star-to-only-a-few-of-the-literates-in-listings-environment/117849?noredirect=1#comment376197_117849), the context checking via `\lst@mode`.

```
\documentclass[spanish, 11pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\lstnumcolor}{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode
    \color{DarkGreen}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
  keywords={typeof, new, true, false, catch, function, return, null, catch, switch, var, if, in, while, do, else, case, break, ajax, each, get, post},
  keywordstyle=\color{darkblue}\bfseries,
  keywords=[2]{class, export, boolean, throw, implements, import, this},
  keywordstyle=[2]\color{darkgray}\bfseries,
  identifierstyle=\color{black},
  sensitive=false,
  comment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  commentstyle=\color{FireBrick}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\color{DarkOrange}\ttfamily,
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"
}

\lstdefinestyle{Javascript}{
   language=JavaScript,
   extendedchars=true,
   basicstyle=\footnotesize,
   showstringspaces=false,
   showspaces=false,
   tabsize=2,
   breaklines=true,
   showtabs=false,
   captionpos=b,
   keepspaces,
}

\lstset{
language=Javascript,
style=Javascript,
  numbers=left, numberstyle=\footnotesize, stepnumber=1, numbersep=12pt,
  frame=none, framesep=7pt,
  breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,
  showstringspaces=false,
  upquote=true,
  columns=fullflexible,
  showstringspaces=false,
  keywordstyle=\color{DarkBlue},
  captionpos=b,
  extendedchars=true,
  literate=
  {0}{{{\lstnumcolor0}}}1
  {1}{{{\lstnumcolor1}}}1
  {2}{{{\lstnumcolor2}}}1
  {3}{{{\lstnumcolor3}}}1
  {4}{{{\lstnumcolor4}}}1
  {5}{{{\lstnumcolor5}}}1
  {6}{{{\lstnumcolor6}}}1
  {7}{{{\lstnumcolor7}}}1
  {8}{{{\lstnumcolor8}}}1
  {9}{{{\lstnumcolor9}}}1
  {á}{{\'a}}1 
  {é}{{\'e}}1
  {í}{{\'i}}1
  {ó}{{\'o}}1
  {ú}{{\'u}}1
  {Á}{{\'A}}1
  {É}{{\'E}}1
  {Í}{{\'I}}1
  {Ó}{{\'O}}1
  {Ú}{{\'U}}1
  {¡}{{!`}}1
  {¿}{{?`}}1
  {·}{{$\cdot$}}1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
function manageLanguage(text)
{ // Language options in interface and errors
    String str4 = "Numbers 123 and 4 in string"; // Numbers 123 and 4 in comment
    switch (language)
    {
        case "Welcome":
        return '¡Bienvenido a '

        case "Browse":
        return '<b>Navega</b> por tu disco duro y selecciona lo(s) fichero(s) a visualizar o simplemente <b>arrástralos</b> al área del botón'

        case "Default":
        return 'Ejemplo por Defecto'
    }

    case "Catalan":
        switch (text)
        {

        case "AlreadySession":
        return 'Ja tens una sessió oberta. Sel·lecciona Nou al menú Fitxer per tancarla i apujar nous fitxers.'

        //var start = (Math.round(this.x*100)/100);
                if (start % intervals == 0)         
                return "<b>" + manageLanguage("Interval") +":</b> [" + Math.round(this.x*10)/10 + " - " + Math.round((this.x+intervals)*10)/10+"]<br/><b>" + manageLanguage(this.series.name) + ":</b> " + this.y + " ";
                else return false; //"<b>" + manageLanguage("Interval") +":</b> [" + this.key + " - " + (this.key+intervals)+"]<br/><b>" + manageLanguage(this.series.name) + ":</b> " + this.y;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remark:**

- The `literate` feature does not work too well for numbers inside strings and comments. The spaces after the numbers are gobbled. As workaround option `keepspaces` can be used, see question ["listings bug: space after literate replacement lost with spaceflexible/fullflexible columns"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41954/16967) (Thanks Jubobs
  for the [hint](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83544/how-to-apply-the-star-to-only-a-few-of-the-literates-in-listings-environment/117849?noredirect=1#comment376257_117849)).

**Limitation:**

- Numbers inside identifiers are colored, too.

### Package `listingsutf8`

The trick with converting UTF-8 to a 8-bit encoding via package `listingsutf8` only works for `\lstinputlisting`. Thus the code needs to be put into a separate file. But then `utf8/latin1` (or `utf8/x-iso-8859-1`) works together with `literate=*...` for the digits excluding comments.

Comment: One problem with you approach is that literal replacements of digits also occur in strings, which the OP doesn't want. You can get around that problem by using the following definition for your \lstnumcolor macro instead: `\newcommand*{\lstnumcolor}{\ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode \color{DarkGreen}\fi}`. See this answer in which I used the same trick.

Comment: @Jubobs: Thanks, answer updated. However severe limitations remain, see answer.

Comment: The space problem can be fixed by using the `keepspaces` option. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46695/21891.