# Do not apply literate option in comments

Tags: listings

I defined my own programming language using `listings` and, to do so, I had to use the `literate` option a lot in my definition. For example, to make parentheses bold and green, I did this:

```
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0, 0.65, 0.2}
\lstdefinelanguage{lang}{
  comment=[l]{\#},
  literate=
    {(}{{{\textbf{\color{darkgreen}(}}}}1
    {)}{{{\textbf{\color{darkgreen})}}}}1
}
```

It works fine. However, I want the replacements defined in the `literate` option *not* to be applied inside comments. For example:

```
(a b c)   # These parentheses should be green
# (a b c) # These shouldn't
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Can you show a minimal example?

Comment: @egreg I edited the question and added more detail

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proper fix, but you can work around the problem in specific cases by escaping the listings environment.

```
\lstset{
  escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
}

% ...

\begin{lstlisting}[language=lang]
    (a b c)
    # (*@{\color{black} (}@*)a b c(*@{\color{black} )}@*)
\end{lstlisting}
```

(You might need to change "black" to the same color you use for comments.)

Answer (score 0):

Adding star character should help. Ignoring both comments and strings.

```
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0, 0.65, 0.2}
\lstdefinelanguage{lang}{
    comment=[l]{\#},
    literate=
    *{(}{{{\textbf{\color{darkgreen}(}}}}1
    {)}{{{\textbf{\color{darkgreen})}}}}1
}
```

[Found here: How to apply the star (*) to only a few of the literates in listings environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83544/how-to-apply-the-star-to-only-a-few-of-the-literates-in-listings-environment)