# Why is listings ignoring my whitespace?

Tags: listings

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{jslistings}

\begin{document}

Test: \lstinline[language=JavaScript]!import {function} from "@icm/service-name";!

\end{document}
```

results in

[image: > Test: import {function}from "@icm/service-name";]

Why does it remove the space between `}` and `from`?

---

**Edit:** I am using a custom language definition:

```
\ProvidesPackage{jslistings}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[pdftex]{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\definecolor{jskeywords}{HTML}{E4D00A}% JavaScript keywords
\definecolor{jsextkeywords}{HTML}{FF6700}% JavaScript extended keywords

\definecolor{identifiers}{HTML}{645452} % identfiers
\definecolor{string}{HTML}{B57281} % string literals
\definecolor{allcomment}{HTML}{808080} % comment

\definecolor{nodejs}{HTML}{629755} % Nodejs keywords
\definecolor{testing}{HTML}{4169E1} % Node.js assert, jasmine
\definecolor{express}{HTML}{FF8C69} % Express.js
\definecolor{linenumber}{HTML}{996515} % line number
\definecolor{apricot}{HTML}{98777B} % numbers
\definecolor{linenofill}{HTML}{BEBEBE} % line number fill color
\definecolor{antiquefuchsia}{HTML}{915C83} % braces
\definecolor{ballblue}{HTML}{21ABCD} % braces

\definecolor{captioncolor}{rgb}{0.39, 0.33, 0.32} % caption color
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{font={color=captioncolor, small,tt}}

\captionsetup[lstlisting]{font={color=captioncolor, small, tt}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+17pt\relax}{0.4pt}\vskip1pt#1#2#3}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={sf},labelsep=space,labelfont=bf}

\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
    alsoletter={.},
    keywords={arguments,await,break,case,catch,class,const,continue,debugger,default,delete,do,else,enum,eval,export,extends,false,finally,for,function,if,implements,import,in,instanceof,interface,let,new,null,package,private,protected,public,return,static,super,switch,this,throw,true,try,typeof,var,void,while,with,yield}, % JavaScript ES6 keywords
    keywordstyle=\color{jskeywords}\bfseries,
    ndkeywords={add, apply, args, Array, Array.from, Array.isArray, Array.of , Array.prototype, ArrayBuffer, bind, Boolean, call, charAt, charCodeAt, clear, codePointAt, concat, constructor, copyWithin, DataView, Date, Date.now, Date.parse, Date.prototype, Date.UTC, decodeURI, decodeURIComponent, encodeURI, encodeURIComponent, endsWith, entries, Error, Error.prototype, EvalError, every, false, fill, filter, find, findIndex, Float32Array, Float64Array, forEach, FulfillPromise, Function, Function.length, get, getDate, getDay, getFullYear, getHours, getMilliseconds, getMinutes, getMonth, getSeconds, getTime, getTimezoneOffset, getUTCDate, getUTCDay, getUTCFullYear, getUTCHours, getUTCMilliseconds, getUTCMinutes, getUTCMonth, getUTCSeconds, has,hasInstance, hasOwnProperty, ignoreCase, includes, indexOf, indexOf, Infinity, Int8Array, Int16Array, Int32Array, isConcatSpreadable, isFinite, isNaN, IsPromise, isPrototypeOf, Iterable, iterator, join, JSON, JSON.parse, JSON.stringify, keys, lastIndexOf, lastIndexOf, length, localeCompare, map, Map, match, match, Math, Math.abs , Math.acos, Math.acosh, Math.asin, Math.asinh, Math.atan, Math.atan2, Math.atanh, Math.cbrt, Math.ceil, Math.clz32, Math.cos, Math.cosh,  Math.E, Math.exp, Math.expm1, Math.floor, Math.fround, Math.hypot, Math.imul, Math.LN2, Math.LN10, Math.log, Math.log1p, Math.log2, Math.LOG2E, Math.log10, Math.LOG10E, Math.max, Math.min, Math.PI, Math.pow, Math.random, Math.round, Math.sign, Math.sin, Math.sinh, Math.sqrt, Math.SQRT1_2, Math.SQRT2, Math.tan, Math.tanh, Math.trunc, message, multiline, name, NaN, NewPromiseCapability, next, normalize, null, Number, Number.EPSILON, Number.isFinite, Number.isInteger, Number.isNaN, Number.isSafeInteger, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, Number.MAX_VALUE, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER, Number.MIN_VALUE, Number.NaN, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, Number.parseFloat, Number.parseInt, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Number.prototype, Object, Object, Object.assign, Object.create, Object.defineProperties, Object.defineProperty, Object.freeze, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor, Object.getOwnPropertyNames, Object.getOwnPropertySymbols, Object.getPrototypeOf, Object.is, Object.isExtensible, Object.isFrozen, Object.isSealed, Object.keys, Object.preventExtensions, Object.prototype, Object.seal, Object.setPrototypeOf, of, parseFloat, parseInt, pop, Promise, Promise.all , Promise.race, Promise.reject, Promise.resolve, PromiseReactionJob, propertyIsEnumerable, prototype, Proxy, Proxy.revocable , push, RangeError, reduce, reduceRight, ReferenceError, Reflect, Reflect.apply, Reflect.construct , Reflect.defineProperty, Reflect.deleteProperty, Reflect.enumerate, Reflect.get, Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor, Reflect.getPrototypeOf, Reflect.has, Reflect.isExtensible, Reflect.ownKeys, Reflect.preventExtensions, Reflect.set, Reflect.setPrototypeOf, Reflection, RegExp, RegExp, RegExp.prototype, repeat, replace, replace, reverse, search, search, Set, set, setDate, setFullYear, setHours, setMilliseconds, setMinutes, setMonth, setSeconds, setTime, setUTCDate, setUTCFullYear, setUTCHours, setUTCMilliseconds, setUTCMinutes, setUTCMonth, setUTCSeconds, shift, slice, slice, some, sort, species, splice, split, split, startsWith, String, String.fromCharCode, String.fromCodePoint, String.raw, substring, Symbol, Symbol.for, Symbol.hasInstance, Symbol.isConcatSpreadable, Symbol.iterator, Symbol.keyFor, Symbol.match, Symbol.prototype, Symbol.replace, Symbol.replace, Symbol.search, Symbol.species, Symbol.split, Symbol.toPrimitive, Symbol.toStringTag, Symbol.unscopables, SyntaxError, then, toDateString, toExponential, toFixed, toISOString, toJSON, toLocaleDateString, toLocaleLowerCase, toLocaleString, toLocaleString, toLocaleString, toLocaleString, toLocaleTimeString, toLocaleUpperCase, toLowerCase, toPrecision, toPrimitive, toString, toStringTag, toTimeString, toUpperCase, toUTCString, TriggerPromiseReactions, trim, true, TypeError, Uint8Array, Uint8ClampedArray, Uint16Array, Uint32Array, undefined, unscopables, unshift, URIError, valueOf, WeakMap, WeakSet
    }, % JavaScript extended keywords
    ndkeywordstyle=\color{jsextkeywords}\bfseries,
    identifierstyle=\color{identifiers},
    sensitive=true,
    stringstyle=\color{string}\ttfamily,
    morestring=[b]",
    morestring=[d]',
    morestring=[s][\color{string}\ttfamily]{`}{`},
    commentstyle=\color{red}\itshape,
    morecomment=[l][\color{allcomment}]{//},
    morecomment=[s][\color{allcomment}]{/*}{*/},
    morecomment=[s][\color{allcomment}]{/**}{*/},
    emph={app.all, app.delete, app.disable, app.disabled, app.enable, app.enabled, app.engine, app.get, app.listen, app.locals, app.METHOD, app.mountpath, app.param, app.path, app.post, app.put, app.render, app.route, app.set, app.use, express, express.Router, express.static, req.acceptLanguages, req.accepts, req.acceptsCharsets, req.acceptsEncodings, req.app, req.baseUrl, req.body, req.cookies, req.fresh, req.get, req.hostname, req.ip, req.ips, req.is, req.method, req.originalUrl, req.param, req.params, req.path, req.protocol, req.query, req.range, req.route, req.secure, req.signedCookies, req.stale, req.subdomains, req.xhr, res.app, res.append, res.attachment, res.clearCookie, res.cookies, res.download, res.end, res.format, res.get, res.headersSent, res.json, res.jsonp, res.links, res.locals, res.location, res.redirect, res.render, res.sendFile, res.sendStatus, res.set, res.status, res.type, res.vary, router.all, router.METHOD, router.param, router.route, router.use}, % express keywords
    emph={[2]agent.createConnection, agent.destroy, agent.freeSockets, agent.getName, agent.maxFreeSockets, agent.maxSockets, agent.requests, agent.sockets, certificate.exportChallenge, certificate.exportPublicKey, certificate.verifySpkac, child.channel, child.connected, child.disconnect, child.kill, child.pid, child.send, child.stderr, child.stdin, child.stdio, child.stdout, child_process.exec, child_process.execFile, child_process.execFileSync, child_process.execSync, child_process.fork, child_process.spawn, child_process.spawnSync, cipher.final, cipher.getAuthTag, cipher.setAAD, cipher.setAutoPadding, cipher.update, clearImmediate, clearImmediate, clearInterval, clearInterval, clearTimeout, clearTimeout, console, console.assert, console.dir, console.error, console.info, console.log, console.time, console.timeEnd, console.trace, console.warn, decipher.final, decipher.setAAD, decipher.setAuthTag, decipher.setAutoPadding, decipher.update, dgram.createSocket, dgram.createSocket, diffieHellman.computeSecret, diffieHellman.generateKeys, diffieHellman.getGenerator, diffieHellman.getPrime, diffieHellman.getPrivateKey, diffieHellman.getPublicKey, diffieHellman.setPrivateKey, diffieHellman.setPublicKey, diffieHellman.verifyError, dns.getServers, dns.getServers, dns.lookup, dns.lookup, dns.lookupService, dns.resolve, dns.resolve4, dns.resolve6, dns.resolveCname, dns.resolveMx, dns.resolveNaptr, dns.resolveNs, dns.resolvePtr, dns.resolveSoa, dns.resolveSrv, dns.resolveTxt, dns.reverse, dns.setServers, ecdh.computeSecret, ecdh.generateKeys, ecdh.getPrivateKey, ecdh.getPublicKey, ecdh.setPrivateKey, ecdh.setPublicKey, error.address, error.code, error.errno, error.message, error.path, error.port, error.stack, error.syscall, exports, fs.access, fs.accessSync, fs.appendFile, fs.appendFileSync, fs.chmod, fs.chmodSync, fs.chown, fs.chownSync, fs.close, fs.closeSync, fs.constants, fs.createReadStream, fs.createWriteStream, fs.exists, global, http.createServer, http.get, http.globalAgent, http.request, https.createServer, https.get, https.globalAgent, https.request, message.destroy, message.headers, message.httpVersion, message.method, message.rawHeaders, message.rawTrailers, message.setTimeout, message.socket, message.statusCode, message.statusMessage, message.trailers, message.url, module, module.children, module.exports, module.filename, module.id, module.loaded, module.parent, module.require, os.arch, os.constants, os.cpus, os.endianness, os.EOL, os.freemem, os.homedir, os.hostname, os.loadavg, os.networkInterfaces, os.platform, os.release, os.tmpdir, os.totalmem, os.type, os.uptime, os.userInfo, path.basename, path.delimiter, path.dirname, path.extname, path.format, path.isAbsolute, path.join, path.normalize, path.parse, path.posix, path.relative, path.resolve, path.sep, path.win32, process, process.abort, process.arch, process.argv, process.argv0, process.channel, process.chdir, process.config, process.connected, process.cpuUsage, process.cwd, process.disconnect, process.emitWarning, process.env, process.execArgv, process.execPath, process.exit, process.exitCode, process.getegid, process.geteuid, process.getgid, process.getgroups, process.getuid, process.hrtime, process.initgroups, process.kill, process.mainModule, process.memoryUsage, process.nextTick, process.pid, process.platform, process.release, process.send, process.setegid, process.seteuid, process.setgid, process.setgroups, process.setuid, process.stderr, process.stdin, process.stdout, process.title, process.umask, process.uptime, process.version, process.versions, querystring.escape, querystring.parse, querystring.stringify, querystring.unescape, r.clearLine, readable.pause, readable.pipe, readable.push, readable.push, readable.read, readable.read, readable.resume, readable.setEncoding, readable.unpipe, readable.unshift, readable.wrap, readable._read, readStream.bytesRead, readStream.isRaw, readStream.path, readStream.setRawMode, repl.start, request.abort, request.aborted, request.end, request.flushHeaders, request.setNoDelay, request.setSocketKeepAlive, request.setTimeout, request.write, require, require.cache, require.extensions, response.addTrailers, response.end, response.finished, response.getHeader, response.getHeaderNames, response.getHeaders, response.hasHeader, response.headersSent, response.removeHeader, response.sendDate, response.setHeader, response.setTimeout, response.statusCode, response.statusMessage, response.write, response.writeContinue, response.writeHead, rl.clearScreenDown, rl.close, rl.createInterface, rl.cursorTo, rl.emitKeypressEvents, rl.moveCursor, rl.pause, rl.prompt, rl.question, rl.resume, rl.setPrompt, rl.write, script.runInNewContext, script.runInThisContext, server.addContext, server.address, server.address, server.close, server.close, server.connections, server.getTicketKeys, server.listen, server.listen, server.setTicketKeys, server.setTimeout, server.setTimeout, server.timeout, server.timeout, setImmediate, setInterval, setTimeout, socket.addMembership, socket.address, socket.bind, socket.bind, socket.close, socket.dropMembership, socket.ref, socket.send, socket.setBroadcast, socket.setMulticastLoopback, socket.setMulticastTTL, socket.setTTL, socket.unref, stream.Readable, stringDecoder.end, stringDecoder.write, timeout.ref, timeout.unref, tls.connect, tls.createSecureContext, tls.createServer, tls.getCiphers, tlsSocket.address, tlsSocket.authorizationError, tlsSocket.authorized, tlsSocket.encrypted, tlsSocket.getCipher, tlsSocket.getEphemeralKeyInfo, tlsSocket.getPeerCertificate, tlsSocket.getProtocol, tlsSocket.getSession, tlsSocket.getTLSTicket, tlsSocket.localAddress, tlsSocket.localPort, tlsSocket.remoteAddress, tlsSocket.remoteFamily, tlsSocket.remotePort, tlsSocket.renegotiate, tlsSocket.setMaxSendFragment, transform._flush, transform._transform, util.debuglog, util.deprecate, util.format, util.inherits, util.inspect, v8.getHeapStatistics, v8.setFlagsFromString, vm.createContext, vm.isContext, vm.runInContext, vm.runInDebugContext, vm.runInNewContext, vm.runInThisContext, watcher.close, worker.disconnect, worker.exitedAfterDisconnect, worker.id, worker.isConnected, worker.isDead, worker.kill, worker.process, worker.send, worker.suicide, writable.cork, writable.end, writable.setDefaultEncoding, writable.write, writeStream.bytesWritten, writeStream.columns, writeStream.path, writeStream.rows, zlib, zlib.createGunzip, zlib.createGzip, zlib.createInflate, zlib.createInflateRaw, zlib.createUnzip, zlib.deflate, zlib.deflateRaw, zlib.deflateRawSync, zlib.deflateSync, zlib.gunzip, zlib.gunzipSync, zlib.gzip, zlib.gzipSync, zlib.inflate, zlib.inflateRaw, zlib.inflateRawSync, zlib.inflateSync, zlib.unzip, zlib.unzipSync, __dirname, __filename}, % Node.js keywords
    emph={[3] assert, assert.deepEqual, assert.deepStrictEqual, assert.doesNotThrow, assert.equal, assert.fail, assert.ifError, assert.notDeepEqual, assert.notDeepStrictEqual, assert.notEqual, assert.notStrictEqual, assert.ok, assert.strictEqual, assert.throws, describe, toBe, it, xdescribe, beforeEach, afterEach, beforeAll, afterAll, expect, it, xit, xdiscribe, pending, and.callThrough, and.returnValue, and.returnValues, and.callFake, and.throwError, and.stub, .not, .calls.any, .calls.count, .calls.argsFor, .calls.allArgs, .calls.all, .calls.mostRecent, .calls.first, .calls.reset, jasmine.createSpy, jasmine.createSpyObj, jasmine.any, jasmine.anything, jasmine.objectContaining, jasmine.arrayContaining, jasmine.stringMatching, asymmetricMatch,  jasmine.clock, .not.toBeTruthy, .toBeTruthy, .not.toBeFalsy, .toBeFalsy, .not.toBeDefined .toBeDefined, .not.toBeNull .toBeNull, .not.toEqual .toEqual, .not.toBeCloseTo .toBeCloseTo, .not.toContain, .toContain, .not.toMatch, .toMatch, .not.toBeGreaterThan, .toBeGreaterThan, .not.toBeLessThan, .toBeLessThan, .toThrow, .not.toThrow, .toBeNull, .not.toBeNull, .toBeDefined, .not.toBeDefined}, % Node.js Assert, Jasmine, ... keywords
}

  \lstset{
   basicstyle=\normalsize\linespread{1.1}\footnotesize\ttfamily,
   language=JavaScript,
   frame=top,frame=bottom,
   breaklines=true,
   showstringspaces=false,
   tabsize=2,
   upquote = true,
   numbers=left,
   numberstyle=\tiny,
   stepnumber=1,
   numbersep=5pt,
   numberblanklines=false,
   xleftmargin=17pt,
   framexleftmargin=17pt,
   framexrightmargin=17pt,
   framexbottommargin=5pt,
   framextopmargin=5pt,
   alsoother={.},
   captionpos=t,
   literate=
            *{\{}{{\textcolor{antiquefuchsia}{\{}}}{1}% punctuators
            {\}}{{\textcolor{antiquefuchsia}{\}}}}{1}%
            {(}{{\textcolor{antiquefuchsia}{(}}}1%
            {)}{{\textcolor{antiquefuchsia}{)}}}1%
            {[}{{\textcolor{antiquefuchsia}{[}}}1%
            {]}{{\textcolor{antiquefuchsia}{]}}}1%
            {...}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{...}}}1%
            {;}{{\textcolor{antiquefuchsia}{;}}}1%
            {,}{{\textcolor{antiquefuchsia}{,}}}1%
            {>}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{>}}}1%
            {<}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{<}}}1%
            {<=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{<=}}}1%
            {>=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{>=}}}1%
            {==}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{==}}}1%
            {!=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{!=}}}1%
            {===}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{===}}}1%
            {!==}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{!==}}}1%
            {+}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{+}}}1%
            {-}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{-}}}1%
            {*}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{*}}}1%
            {\%}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{\%}}}1%
            {++}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{++}}}1%
            {--}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{--}}}1%
            {<<}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{<<}}}1%
            {>>}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{>>}}}1%
            {>>>}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{>>>}}}1%
            {=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{=}}}1%
            {&}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{&}}}1%
            {|}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{|}}}1%
            {^}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{^}}}1%
            {!}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{!}}}1%
            {~}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{~}}}1%
            {&&}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{&&}}}1%
            {||}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{||}}}1%
            {?}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{?}}}1%
            {:}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{:}}}1%
            {=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{=}}}1%
            {+=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{+=}}}1%
            {-=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{-=}}}1%
            {*=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{*=}}}1%
            {\%=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{\%=}}}1%
            {<<=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{<<=}}}1%
            {>>=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{>>=}}}1%
            {>>>=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{>>>=}}}1%
            {&=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{&=}}}1%
            {|=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{|=}}}1%
            {^=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{^=}}}1%
            {=>}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{=>}}}1%
            {\\b}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{\\b}}}1% escape sequences
            {\\t}{{\textcolor{apricot}{\\t}}}{1}%
            {\\n}{{\textcolor{apricot}{\\n}}}{1}%
            {\\v}{{\textcolor{apricot}{\\v}}}{1}%
            {\\f}{{\textcolor{apricot}{\\f}}}{1}%
            {\\r}{{\textcolor{apricot}{\\r}}}{1}%
            {\\"}{{\textcolor{apricot}{\\"}}}{1}%
            {\\'}{{\textcolor{apricot}{\\'}}}{1}%
            {\\}{{\textcolor{apricot}{\\}}}{1}%
            {0}{{\textcolor{apricot}{0}}}{1}% numbers
            {1}{{\textcolor{apricot}{1}}}{1}%
            {2}{{\textcolor{apricot}{2}}}{1}%
            {3}{{\textcolor{apricot}{3}}}{1}%
            {4}{{\textcolor{apricot}{4}}}{1}%
            {5}{{\textcolor{apricot}{5}}}{1}%
            {6}{{\textcolor{apricot}{6}}}{1}%
            {7}{{\textcolor{apricot}{7}}}{1}%
            {8}{{\textcolor{apricot}{8}}}{1}%
            {9}{{\textcolor{apricot}{9}}}{1}%
            {.0}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.0}}}{2}%
            {.1}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.1}}}{2}%
            {.2}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.2}}}{2}%
            {.3}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.3}}}{2}%
            {.4}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.4}}}{2}%
            {.5}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.5}}}{2}%
            {.6}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.6}}}{2}%
            {.7}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.7}}}{2}%
            {.8}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.8}}}{2}%
            {.9}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.9}}}{2},%
   emphstyle={\color{express}}, % express
   emphstyle={[2]\color{nodejs}}, % node.js
   emphstyle={[3]\color{testing}}, % jasmine ...
   numberstyle=\normalfont\tiny\textcolor{linenumber} % line number
}
```

Comment: Please post a MWE here. External links are discouraged because your question might become meaningless if/when the link disappears (next week, or next year, or... ).

Comment: @campa I posted all relevant code on here. I just added the link with boilerplate for convenience

Comment: That is not relevant for users in the future as campa menttions. Please make a self contatined example and post it here. No external links unless it is for nonstandard classes. Your sniplet will not compile when added to the simplest of sample documents.

Comment: You did not post all relevant code here. Relevant is that you define curly braces as literate characters. If you had taken the time to prepare an actual minimal working example (which includes reducing the jslistings.sty), you would have noticed that the desired behaviour is retained once you remove the curly braces from the list of literates. Thus, the question should be: Why are empty spaces removed after a literate character? Unfortunately, I don't know a solution.

Comment: (Posting this as comment and not answer, because there is some bit I'm not sure about.) There is a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41954/82917) with an answer which suggests using the `keepspaces` option. This seems to work also here, although in the linked question the problem sems to be related to the use of flexible columns.

Comment: @campa That's the solution! Please post an answer and I will accept it right away!

Comment: I don't know, thee issue is not new, see also [Spacing issue with literate in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/445691/82917). I'm trying to find a duplicate.

Comment: @campa Or mark as duplicate - also alright with me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listings package does not support JavaScript. Either you switch to a different package to display your code, or you define it yourself. Fortunately other folks had the same issue and published code.

I took the JavaScript definition below from here: https://github.com/ghammock/LaTeX_Listings_JavaScript_ES6

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[pdftex]{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage{caption}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
% \usepackage{jslistings}

\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
  morekeywords=[1]{break, continue, delete, else, for, function, if, in,
    new, return, this, typeof, var, void, while, with},
  % Literals, primitive types, and reference types.
  morekeywords=[2]{false, null, true, boolean, number, undefined,
    Array, Boolean, Date, Math, Number, String, Object},
  % Built-ins.
  morekeywords=[3]{eval, parseInt, parseFloat, escape, unescape},
  sensitive,
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  morecomment=[l]//,
  morecomment=[s]{/**}{*/}, % JavaDoc style comments
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"
}[keywords, comments, strings]

\begin{document}
%\pagenumbering{gobble}

\clearpage
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
Test: \lstinline[language=JavaScript]!import {function} from "@icm/service-name";!
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\vfill 
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image: pic of rendered code]

The issue has been discussed years ago here: [language option supported in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89574/4736) and here: [\listings code style for HTML5 (CSS, HTML, JavaScript)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99500/4736)