# Blank space after equal-sign in Python-Code-Section of LaTeX-Dokument-PDF by using packages "listings" and "pythonhighlight"

Tags: listings, pdf, code, python

Does anybody know how to set the packages "listings" and "pythonhighlight" for displaying one blank space before (this already works) and after an "=" (and maybe other operation-symbols for future usage)?

I have an appendix section as .tex file:

```
\subsection{DALAtomObjectService}
\label{app:DALAtomObjectService} % chktex 24
Beispiel für die ``Object\_Service\_Atom''-Klasse im Data-Access-Layer (Ausschnitt):

\begin{python}
    class Object_Service_Atom(Object_Service_Abstract):

    def __init__(self):
        self.url = ATOM_BINDING_URL        

    def createDocument(self, repositoryId, properties, **kwargs):
        service = inspect.stack()[0][3]
        kwargs['service'] = service        
        url = self.url + "/" + repositoryId + "/children"
        data = Atom_Properties_Post(
            properties['name'], properties['objectTypeId']).getAtomProperty()
        params = {}
        if 'folderId' in kwargs:
            params['id'] = kwargs['folderId']
        create_response = RS().post(url, params=params, data=data, **kwargs)
        return create_response    
\end{python}
```

This is displayed in the created PDF like this:

````
    1 class Object_Service_Atom(Object_Service_Abstract):
    2
    3    def __init__(self):
    4       self.url =ATOM_BINDING_URL
    5
    6    def createDocument(self, repositoryId, properties, **kwargs):
    7       service =inspect.stack()[0][3]
    8       kwargs[’service’] =service
    9       url =self.url +"/" + repositoryId +"/children"
    10      data =Atom_Properties_Post(
    11         properties[’name’], properties[’objectTypeId’]).getAtomProperty()
    12      params ={}
    13      if ’folderId’ in kwargs:
    14         params[’id’] =kwargs[’folderId’]
    15      create_response =RS().post(url, params=params, data=data, **kwargs)
    16      return create_response```
````

But I don't want the assignments like

> self.url =ATOM_BINDING_URL

but simply like that:

> self.url = ATOM_BINDING_URL

.

In the Packages.tex file in the Section "Allgemein" (General) I have the following settings for the "listings" and "pythonhighlight" packages:

```
% zum Einbinden von Programmcode -----------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pythonhighlight}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{hellgelb}{rgb}{1,1,0.9}
\definecolor{colKeys}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{colIdentifier}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{colComments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{colString}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\lstset{
    float=hbp,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    identifierstyle=\color{colIdentifier},
    keywordstyle=\color{colKeys},
    stringstyle=\color{colString},
    commentstyle=\color{colComments},
    backgroundcolor=\color{hellgelb},
    columns=flexible,
    tabsize=2,
    frame=single,
    extendedchars=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    breaklines=true,
    breakautoindent=true,
    captionpos=b,
    showstringspaces=false
}
\lstdefinelanguage{cs}{
    sensitive=false,
    morecomment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    morestring=[b]", % chktex 18
    morekeywords={
        abstract,event,new,struct,as,explicit,null,switch
        base,extern,object,this,bool,false,operator,throw,
        break,finally,out,true,byte,fixed,override,try,
        case,float,params,typeof,catch,for,private,uint,
        char,foreach,protected,ulong,checked,goto,public,unchecked,
        class,if,readonly,unsafe,const,implicit,ref,ushort,
        continue,in,return,using,decimal,int,sbyte,virtual,
        default,interface,sealed,volatile,delegate,internal,short,void,
        do,is,sizeof,while,double,lock,stackalloc,
        else,long,static,enum,namespace,string},
}
\lstdefinelanguage{natural}{
    sensitive=false,
    morecomment=[l]{/*},
    morestring=[b]", % chktex 18
    morestring=[b]',
    alsodigit={-,*},
    morekeywords={
        DEFINE,DATA,LOCAL,END-DEFINE,WRITE,CALLNAT,PARAMETER,USING,
        IF,NOT,END-IF,ON,*ERROR-NR,ERROR,END-ERROR,ESCAPE,ROUTINE,
        PERFORM,SUBROUTINE,END-SUBROUTINE,CONST,END-FOR,END,FOR,RESIZE,
        ARRAY,TO,BY,VALUE,RESET,COMPRESS,INTO,EQ},
}
\lstdefinelanguage{php}{
    sensitive=false,
    morecomment=[l]{/*},
    morestring=[b]", % chktex 18
    morestring=[b]',
    alsodigit={-,*},
    morekeywords={
        abstract,and,array,as,break,case,catch,cfunction,class,clone,const,
        continue,declare,default,do,else,elseif,enddeclare,endfor,endforeach,
        endif,endswitch,endwhile,extends,final,for,foreach,function,global,
        goto,if,implements,interface,instanceof,namespace,new,old_function,or,
        private,protected,public,static,switch,throw,try,use,var,while,xor
        die,echo,empty,exit,eval,include,include_once,isset,list,require,
        require_once,return,print,unset},
}
\lstset{language=python,texcl=true}
\lstset{literate=
  {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1 % chktex 7
  {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
  {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1 % chktex 7
  {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1 % chktex 7
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1 % chktex 7
  {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
  {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
  {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
}
```

I'm using a template, only the two last "\lsets" and the "showstringspaces=false" were later added by me.

There is probably a simple solution, but I have not yet managed to find something with Google that corresponds to what I want. LaTeX is new to me, otherwise I might be able to search more purposefully.

Thanks for help with examples or hints where to look!

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41954/263192

Comment: Thanks! That gives me more insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your spaces back, you can add `keepspaces` or use `columns=fixed` instead of `columns=flexible`.

From the `listings` [manual](https://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf):

> **2.10 Fixed and flexible columns**
> The first thing a reader notices—except different styles for keywords, etc.—is the column alignment.
> [...]
> Currently four column formats are provided: fixed, flexible, space-flexible, and full flexible.
> [...]
> In the abstract one can say: The fixed column format ruins the spacing intended by the font designer, while the flexible formats ruin the column alignment (possibly) intended by the programmer.

and

> `keepspaces=true` tells the package not to drop spaces to fix column alignment and always converts tabulators to spaces.

Comment: Perfect, 'columns=fixed' works and seems to be the best solution for me. I don't need them to be 'flexible' on this. Thank you very much!